# Error: Seg. Fault. Want to copy multiple files

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, file-handling

I wanted to copy multiple files using multi-threading. This ends in error: *segmentation fault*. Cannot figure out where.

What I tried: `print("test");` on different lines, but gives me the same error. I think the main function is correct, something in the `start_routine()` block.

Code:

```
typedef struct filePair
{
    char srcName[100];
    char dstName[100];
} filePair;

void * start_routine(void *arg) //file handling using system calls
{
    char tmp;

    printf("Copying %s to %s.\n", ((filePair *)arg)->srcName, ((filePair *)arg)->dstName);

    int src = open(((filePair *)arg)->srcName, O_RDWR); //open source file
    if (!src)
    {
        printf("Cannot open source file.\n"); //error handling
        exit(0);
    }

    //open dst file
    int dst = open(((filePair *)arg)->dstName, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0641);
    if (!dst)
    {
        printf("Error in destination file.\n"); //error handling
        exit(0);
    }

    while (read(src, &tmp, 1)) //while loop to copy contents
        write(dst, &tmp, 1);

    close(src); //close src and dst files
    close(dst);

    return NULL;
}

//main function...
```

Comment: The correct type is `struct filePair *`.

Comment: @kaylum so every time I cast `(filePair*)` it should be `(struct filePair*)`?

Comment: Need to use brackets as `->` has higher precedence than cast. `((struct filePair *)arg)->src`. But it'll simplify code to make a variable and do the cast once at the start of the function: `struct filePair *fpair = (struct filePair *) arg;`

Comment: @kaylum I tried that, gives me a segmentation fault

Comment: That's because your code has other bugs. `struct filePair * file1; strcpy(file1->src, "file1.dat");` Can't do things like that. `file1` is not a valid pointer and it must not be dereferenced. Do instead:  `struct filePair file1; strcpy(file1.src, "file1.dat");`

Comment: Re, "Any way to find where?" Next time, run the program in a debugger. When the debugger stops the program (or, maybe just the one thread) because of the segfault, you can ask it for a stack trace of the faulted thread.

Comment: Nowhere do you ever create a `filePair`. You create variables of type "pointer to `filePair`", but you never make them actually, you know, point to a `filePair`.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the type is `struct filePair`. A common way to make the usage of the type shorter is to incorporate a `typedef`:

```c
typedef struct
{
    char src[100];
    char dst[100];
} filePair;
```

Then, you can refer to teh `filePair` type.

Answer (score 1):

1.cause of segmentation fault in code is improper usage of pointers.
creating pointers of type **filePair** and not allocating sufficient memory for those pointers will cause segmentation fault. If we allocate sufficient memory for those pointers, it won't be a problem anymore.

2. prototype for pthread_create() is

> int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,void
> *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);

before passing *file1 in pthread_create() we should typecast file1 pointer to be of type
(void *).

Here I am providing a simple version without using pointers for **filePair**, but using **filePair** instances instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>     /* printf, stderr */
#include <sys/types.h> /* pid_t */
#include <unistd.h>    /* fork */
#include <stdlib.h>    /* atoi */
#include <errno.h>     /* errno */
#include <pthread.h>   /* pthread */
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h> /* file handling */
#include <time.h>  /* CLOCK */
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char srcName[100];
    char dstName[100];
} filePair;

void * start_routine(void *arg) //file handling using system calls
{
    char tmp;

    printf("Copying %s to %s.\n", ((filePair *)arg)->srcName, ((filePair *)arg)->dstName);

    int src = open(((filePair *)arg)->srcName, O_RDWR); //open source file
    if (!src)
    {
        printf("Cannot open source file.\n"); //error handling
        exit(0);
    }

    //open dst file
    int dst = open(((filePair *)arg)->dstName, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0641);
    if (!dst)
    {
        printf("Error in destination file.\n"); //error handling
        exit(0);
    }

    while (read(src, &tmp, 1)) //while loop to copy contents
        write(dst, &tmp, 1);

    close(src); //close src and dst files
    close(dst);

    return NULL;
}


/* main function */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread1; //Threads init
    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_t thread3;
    pthread_t thread4;
    pthread_t thread5;

    filePair  file1;
    strcpy(file1.srcName, "file1.dat");
    strcpy(file1.dstName, "copy1.dat");

    filePair  file2;
    strcpy(file2.srcName, "file2.dat");
    strcpy(file2.dstName, "copy2.dat");

    filePair  file3;
    strcpy(file3.srcName, "file3.dat");
    strcpy(file3.dstName, "copy3.dat");

    filePair  file4;
    strcpy(file4.srcName, "file4.dat");
    strcpy(file4.dstName, "copy4.dat");

    filePair  file5;
    strcpy(file5.srcName, "file5.dat");
    strcpy(file5.dstName, "copy5.dat");

    printf("\n Before threading.\n\n");

    //Creating threads
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, start_routine, (void *)&file1);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, start_routine, (void *)&file2);
    pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, start_routine, (void *)&file3);
    pthread_create(&thread4, NULL, start_routine, (void *)&file4);
    pthread_create(&thread5, NULL, start_routine, (void *)&file5);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread4, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread5, NULL);

    printf("\n After threading.\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```